# SIGALRM not interrupting long running SVC fitting

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to stop a fitting process for sklearn's `SVC` by using `signal.alarm`, along with an appropriate signal handler that throws an exception.

Below is a MWE

```
  import numpy as np
  from sklearn.svm import SVC
  import signal

  n = int(1e5)
  np.random.seed(1)
  X = np.random.random((n, 100))
  y = np.random.choice(['A', 'B'], size=n)

  def timeout_handler(s, f):
    raise Exception('Timed out')

  def not_interrupting():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)
    signal.alarm(3)
    # this should take on the order of minutes
    SVC().fit(X, y)
    signal.alarm(0)

  def interrupting():
    signal.alarm(3)
    SVC().fit(X, y)
    signal.alarm(0)

  # interrupts (but kills the current python process)
  interrupting()

  # doesn't interrupt as expected within 3 seconds
  not_interrupting()
```

This doesn't seem to work. The exception raised doesn't interrupt execution. However if I don't register a signal handler, as done in `interrupting`, it does interrupt but kills the current python process. Any suggestions?

Additional Info:

- scikit-learn 0.18.1
- Python 3.6.1
- OS X 10.11.16

I think I may have found my own answer. According to the `signal` docs:

> Although Python signal handlers are called asynchronously as far as the Python user is concerned, they can only occur between the “atomic” instructions of the Python interpreter. This means that signals arriving during long calculations implemented purely in C (such as regular expression matches on large bodies of text) may be delayed for an arbitrary amount of time.

I believe `SVC` uses `libsvm`, so that is causing the delay of my signal handler being called.

Comment: what is the platform you are running? Is it Windows or Linux or Mac or Unix?

Comment: @be_good_do_good sorry, should have known better and added that. Additional info added via edit now. Thanks